# Navigation when using jQuerys .load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am loading HTML files into `div` with the class `content`.

So when i click on a menu entry, i just call this function:

```
 function load_content(page_title) {
   $('.content').load(page_title + '.html');
   document.location.hash = page_title;
   if (page_title == "Home") {
     $('#logo_small').hide();
     $('#home_link').hide();
   } else {
     $('#logo_small').show();
     $('#home_link').show();
   }

 };
```

I've tried to save the state through the `document.location.hash`, **but how can i load the content when i navigate back and forth in the browser history?**

> Create a function which is watching the hash and then loading the
>   content or which way is the best?

Comment: Use something like history.js, as it works across most browsers (not just HTML 5). You then catch its `hashchange` event and do your work in that.

Comment: I see... thank you. Do you have good recomandations for tutorials? I don't want to blow up my code just to load and unload content... There are so many functions and i couldn't find any "10 lines of code" which has quality.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look to this plugin http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/ which might do the trick for handling hashchange event.

Comment: That is a very old plugin and I have found other Ben Alman plugins (like BBQ) no longer work with latest coding standards/browsers. Shame as BBQ was quite good.